# Data migration from on-premises MySQL to RDS for MySQL

Tags: mysql, alibaba-cloud-rds

Data Transmission Service can migrate data from on-premises MySQL databases to Alibaba Cloud RDS for MySQL databases without server outage.

To perform incremental data replication, the binlog must be enabled for the source database.

How can I enable binlog in RDS for MySQL on Alibaba Cloud.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

As per Alibaba Cloud Data Transmission Service https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/26621.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.a3.3.33ae47adUihT06 binary log must be enabled on the **source** MySQL database.

You can follow this procedure to enable MySQL binary log https://oguya.ch/posts/2016-01-07-enable-mysql-binlog/

Answer (score 0):

You can enable binary log in RDS for MySQL on Alibaba Cloud by just adding `log_bin` parameter under `[mysqld] section` in your `my.cnf` config file.

> log_bin = mysql-bin